# Powershell Search for specific string, then add text right after it

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty sure this is can be done easily but i couldn't find the answer.
Suppose i have a text file with a bunch of lines in it.
Contents of the text file below

```
dbuser=admin
dbpassword=
```

So in Powershell I want to find the string "dbpassword=" and add the text "password" right after the =.
Solutions I've searched for have -replace but i don't want to replace the line, just want to add "password" to it.

Can anyone share what the Powershell code may be?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your contributions, I ended up finding this solution.

```
$config = Get-Content path\to\file\somefile.txt
$password = abcdef
$config -replace "dbpassword=.*",("dbpassword="+$password) |
    Set-Content path\to\file\somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that everything after the `=` character becomes 'password'.

```
Get-Content -Path '.\bunchoflines.txt' |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -match '^dbpassword=' ? 'dbpassword=password' : $_ }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, is it possible to add the text 'password' without replacing 'dbpassword=' as well?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But that would create risk of adding onto an existing password or not removing whitespace such as SPACE and HORIZONTAL TAB characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you care if it's replaced, but you could just output that line followed by the password instead. Assuming you want to update the file I'd use Set-Content to write it and a switch statement to read the file.

```
$inputfile = '\path\to\inputfile.txt'

Set-Content -Path $inputfile -value $(
    switch -Regex -File $inputfile {
        '^dbpassword=' {"$($_)password"}
        default {$_}
    }
)
```